# Collision function not working?

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

So I'm trying to create a function that compares every corner of two objects by the x,y coordinates to check if any of the corners overlap(aka collide.) All of my variables have been defined, I get no errors, and as far as I can tell there's nothing wrong. The problem is the console.logs that say "Score" never go off, even when I'm directly inside of them. The coordinate.logs go off and I don't get any errors. Any ideas?

```
function blockCollision(x1, y1, width1, height1, x2, y2, width2, height2) {
    //Object 1

    c1x = x1 //Top Left
    c2x = x1 + width2 //Top Right
    c3x = x1 - height2 //Bottom left
    c4x = x1 - height2 + width2 //Bottom Right

    c1y = y1 //Top Left
    c2y = y1 + width2 //Top Right
    c3y = y1 - height2 //Bottom left
    c4y = y1 - height2 + width2 //Bottom Right
    //Object 2

    c5x = x2 //Top Left
    c6x = x2 + width2 //Top Right
    c7x = x2 - height2 //Bottom left
    c8x = x2 - height2 + width2 //Bottom Right

    c5y = y2 //Top Left
    c6y = y2 + width2 //Top Right
    c7y = y2 - height2 //Bottom left
    c8y = y2 - height2 + width2 //Bottom Right
    if (Math.hypot(c1x-c8x, c1x-c8y) <= 15) {
        console.log ("Score")

    }
    if (Math.hypot(c2x-c7x, c2x-c7y) <= 15) {
        console.log ("Score")

    }
    if (Math.hypot(c3x-c6x, c3x-c6y) <= 15) {
        console.log ("Score")

    }
    if (Math.hypot(c4x-c5x, c4x-c5y) <= 15) {
        console.log ("Score")

    }
    console.log (c1x, c1y)
    console.log (c2x, c2y)
    console.log (c3x, c3y)
    console.log (c4x, c4y)
    console.log (c5x, c5y)
    console.log (c6x, c6y)
    console.log (c7x, c7y)
    console.log (c8x, c8y)


}
```

(later in code)

```
blockCollision(ax, ay, avatar.width, avatar.height, platform1x, platform1y, platform.width, platform.height)
```

**Edit**

Okay so it would appear that the second code snippet by @Chris G worked for what I needed. (I had to tweak it a little bit to work for my situation)

```
    function blockCollision(x1, y1, width1, height1, x2, y2, width2, height2) {


          var c1x = x1 + width1 / 2, //Finds center
            c2x = x2 + width2 / 2; //Finds center
          var c1y = y1 + height1 / 2, //Finds center
            c2y = y2 + height2 / 2; // Finds center
          // collision coefficients
          var tx = (c1x - c2x) / ((width1 + width2) / 2); //Finds the distance of the two centers
          var ty = (c1y - c2y) / ((height1 + height2) / 2); //Finds the distance of the two centers

          if (tx < -1 || tx > 1 || ty < -1 || ty > 1) return false; //Checks that the overlap is valid
          // tx, ty points to overlap center
          if (y1 < y2 && Math.abs(y2 - y1) > Math.abs(x2 - x1) ) { //Checks that object 1 is above object 2
            console.log("above")
          } else if (y1 > y2) { //Checks that object 1 is below object 2
            console.log("below")
          } else if (x1 > x2) { //Checks that object 1 is to the right of object 2
            console.log("right side") 
          } else if (x1 < x2) { //Checks that object 1 is to the left of object 2
            console.log("left side")
          }
```

Thank you all so much for the help I honestly thought it would be at least a day before anyone would even respond. You're all incredible, talented people <3

Comment: Don't use global variables. Precede your variable declarations with `var`.

Comment: are you positive you go into the if statements? console.log statements outside and verify the numbers are what you expect.

Comment: width1 and height1 are never used in code

Comment: The first thing I'm noticing is that you're *subtracting* the height from the top Y coordinate instead of adding to it. Is that intentional? In programming we usually use a top-left-origin coordinate system, does your game engine use a bottom-left-origin?

Comment: What's with the `15`? Where's that coming from, and why would it apply to a generic collision check? I also suspect that the main issue with your code is you have `c1x-c8y` instead of `c1y-c8y` and so on as the second arguments of `hypot`.

Comment: @ChrisG The 15 is for a margin of error, as in if the top left corner of object 1 comes within 15 pixels of the bottom right corner of object 2. If I can figure out what's wrong with this code that'll become as small as possible while still working (probably about 1)

Comment: @user308001 Hmm, not sure about that. But I also just noticed that you have this `c4x = x1 - height2 + width2 //Bottom Right` which can't possibly be right, given that the x value of a rectangle's corner has nothing to do with its height.

Comment: @MátéSafranka That's a wonderful observation thank you I was thinking subtracting went down but obviously it doesn't. Unfortunately still not working.

Comment: @Bucket I'm sorry, I'm totally new to JavaScript, started using it 5 days ago. Do you mean after the canvas and context is declared declare the variables with var preceding them, or do you mean declare them with var within the function?

Comment: @user308001 Here's your code, as you intended I guess: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7n62okqr/ (note that I had to basically fix every single corner line, and there's much redundancy)

Comment: @ChrisG c4x and c4y are the coordinates. It's just saying that c4x when combined with c4y will be the coordinates of the corner.

Comment: @user308001 I'm perfectly aware of that...

Comment: Oh I see... you right I'm stupid o.0.

Comment: You're right but the code didn't work. Still no errors just not working.

Comment: @user308001 Here's amended code that returns position coefficients: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5jaoc4g3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rectangular collision function, based on (0,0) being the top left corner:

```
function blockCollision(x1, y1, width1, height1, x2, y2, width2, height2) {
  if (x1 + width1 < x2 || x1 > x2 + width2) return false;
  if (y1 + height1 < y2 || y1 > y2 + height2) return false;
  return true;
}
```

This checks a horizontal overlap, then a vertical overlap. If both are found, there's a collision.

Use it like this:

```
if (blockCollision(ax, ay, avatar.width, avatar.height, platform1x, platform1y, platform.width, platform.height))
  console.log("Score");
```

---

**Edit:**
Here's a second version that returns where the collision took place:

```
function blockCollision(x1, y1, width1, height1, x2, y2, width2, height2) {
  // center coords
  var c1x = x1 + width1 / 2,
    c2x = x2 + width2 / 2;
  var c1y = y1 + height1 / 2,
    c2y = y2 + height2 / 2;
  // collision coefficients
  var tx = (c1x - c2x) / ((width1 + width2) / 2);
  var ty = (c1y - c2y) / ((height1 + height2) / 2);

  if (tx < -1 || tx > 1 || ty < -1 || ty > 1) return false;
  // tx, ty points to overlap center
  return [tx, ty];
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5jaoc4g3/

Comment: This would work however I need to know which side/corner it collides with. Thanks though!

Comment: Oh nevermind had another error 0.o I'll have to edit this to make it apply in my situation but it looks like it'll probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Only two pairs of coordinates are required to position the rectangle on the surface. So it's needed Left + Right X and Top + Bottom Y of each object. Width1 and height1 are used to get right and bottom sides of first object. Similarly width2 and height2 are used for second object.
The modified code:

```
function blockCollision(x1, y1, width1, height1, x2, y2, width2, height2) {
    var c1x, c2x, c3x, c4x;
    var c1y, c2y, c3y, c4y;
    var c5x, c6x, c7x, c8x;
    var c5y, c6y, c7y, c8y;

    //Object 1
    c3x = c1x = x1; //Left X
    c4x = c2x = x1 + width1; //Right X

    c2y = c1y = y1; //Top Y
    c4y = c3y = y1 - height1; //Bottom Y

    //Object 2
    c7x = c5x = x2; //Top X
    c8x = c6x = x2 + width2; //Right X

    c6y = c5y = y2; //Top Y
    c8y = c7y = y2 - height2; //Bottom Y

    if (Math.hypot(c1x-c8x, c1x-c8y) <= 15) {
        console.log ("Score")

    }
    if (Math.hypot(c2x-c7x, c2x-c7y) <= 15) {
        console.log ("Score")

    }
    if (Math.hypot(c3x-c6x, c3x-c6y) <= 15) {
        console.log ("Score")

    }
    if (Math.hypot(c4x-c5x, c4x-c5y) <= 15) {
        console.log ("Score")

    }
    console.log (c1x, c1y)
    console.log (c2x, c2y)
    console.log (c3x, c3y)
    console.log (c4x, c4y)
    console.log (c5x, c5y)
    console.log (c6x, c6y)
    console.log (c7x, c7y)
    console.log (c8x, c8y)
}
```

Comment: This appears to be correct and you fixed all my ridiculous errors, so thank you <3 but it still doesn't work?

Comment: I just tried it with parameters var ax = 0, ay = 2, avatar = {width: 2, height: 2}, platform1x = 1, platform1y = 1, platform = {width: 20, height: 20}; and it works well on my end. One "Score" logged in the console